# Idempotents in commutative ring of characteristic 2 form a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents, positive-characteristic

In a commutative ring of characteristic $2$, I want to show that the        idempotents form a subring. It's probably easiest to directly test that the set of forms a subring. It is easy to verify that the identity element is in the subring, but I'm having trouble verifying the other two properties.

Comment: Can you start writing down what you have left to check? For example, if I have idempotent $x$ and $y$ then $x + y$ should be idempotent. Write out what that means.

Comment: $(x - y)(x - y) = x^2 - xy - yx + y^2 = x^2 + y^2 = x + y = x - y$.

Answer (score 2):

- Notice $1^2 = 1$, so $1$ is idempotent if we are dealing with a unital ring.
- Given idempotents $x$ and $y$, we have

  - $(x+y)^2 = x^2+2xy+y^2 = x + (0) + y = x+y\,,$ so $x+y$ is idempotent.
  - $(xy)^2 = x^2y^2 = xy\,,$ so $xy$ is idempotent.